# trouble with running c++ test on travis ci. Cmake configuration. How run test suite on travis ci?

Tags: c++, cmake, automated-tests, travis-ci

i have a little problem with run test on travis ci. I wrote Cmakelists.txt and .travis.yml files, which contain this code:

```
language: cpp
compiler:
  - gcc
install:
  - sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev
before_script:
  - mkdir build
  - cd build
  - cmake --version
  - cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON ..
script: make && make test
```

and cmakelists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )
project ( CodeProject )
project ( TestProject )

set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14 )
set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED on )

include_directories ( ${CodeProject_SOURCE_DIR}/code_src/ )
include_directories ( ${TestProject_SOURCE_DIR}/test_src/ )

set ( CodeProject_SOURCES ${CodeProject_SOURCE_DIR}/code_src/main.cpp )
set ( TestProject_SOURCES ${TestProject_SOURCE_DIR}/test_src/mainTest.cpp )


set( CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "build/${CodeProject}" )
add_executable( CodeProject ${CodeProject_SOURCES} )
add_executable( TestProject ${TestProject_SOURCES} )
```

When i try build my solution on travis ci, i recieve this kind of message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `test'.  Stop.
The command "make && make test" exited with 2.
```

What problem?

Comment: Have you used [`enable_testing()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/enable_testing.html)? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [**enable testing**](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest) by [`enable_testing()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_testing.html) first. Each test is added by [`add_test()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html) (requires a exe target).

```
# ...

# Enables 'test' target
enable_testing()

# Create your test executable
add_executable(TestProject ${TestProject_SOURCES})
# Register the test
add_test(NAME TestProject COMMAND TestProject)

# Add further tests ...
```